# Where is the source for: "Function application has higher precedence than infix operators" [Haskell]

Tags: haskell, operator-precedence

I'm learning about operator precedence in Haskell. Several places across the web mention that function application has *higher* precedence than operators, but I couldn't find a definitive source for that.

Here is one such mention from [A Gentle Introduction To Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/index.html):

> Function application has higher precedence than any infix operator

There is a section in the [Haskell 98 Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html) that alludes to it:

> normal constructor application has higher precedence than infix constructor application

Where is a definitive source? I would expect it to be included in the Haskell 98 Report, perhaps I'm not reading it correctly.

Comment: function application is a special case, but in general, you can check this right on `ghci` using the `:i` command. For instance, `:i (.)` would tell function composition is right associative with a precedence level equal to 9 (`infixr 9`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find it [here](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html) in the EBNF:

```
exp^10 -> ...
        | fexp

fexp -> [fexp] aexp
```

which basically means that function application has precedence 10, higher than any you are allowed to give to an operator.

Answer (score 6):

The *Haskell Report* is itself a definitive reference, so the quote you found is sufficient.

You can also find the same information in the grammar.

```
fexp -> [fexp] aexp
exp_10 -> ... | fexp
```

You can see that function application has precedence "10" whereas all the infix / prefix operators are 9 or lower.

Comment: Right, though the specific Report quote in the OP seems to refer to _type operators_ rather than value-level infix operators.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that... the information might be most helpful to OP rather than to me, however.