# Why appending at beginning or at end doesn't matter in this functions? Haskell

Tags: list, recursion, append

In haskell [1,2,3,4,5]++[6] gives [1,2,3,4,5,6] but [6]++[1,2,3,4,5] gives [6,1,2,3,4,5]. So it matters if i append at beginning or at end of a list.

But now let's try the same thing in those recursive functions f1 and f2

```
f1 x accumulator | x == 0 = accumulator
                 | otherwise = f1 (x-1) accumulator++[x]
```

Now f2 below is the same function, except that i append the element at the beginning of the list.

```
f2 x accumulator | x == 0 = accumulator
                 | otherwise = f2 (x-1) [x]++accumulator
```

Strangely both functions return the same order for the same input. Why?

For example:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]++[6]
```

returns [1,2,3,4,5,6]

```
[6]++[1,2,3,4,5]
```

returns [6,1,2,3,4,5]

```
f1 6 []
```

returns [1,2,3,4,5,6]

```
f2 6 []
```

returns [1,2,3,4,5,6] too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. You are misleaded because you attribute (falsely) the higher precedence to the `++` operator in the following expressions:

- `f1 (x-1) accumulator++[x]` means `(f1 (x-1) accumulator)++[x]`and **not** `f1 (x-1) (accumulator++[x])`.
- Likewise, `f2 (x-1) [x]++accumulator` means `(f2 (x-1) [x]) ++ accumulator` and **not** `f2 (x-1) ([x]++accumulator)`.

Hence:

```
f1 6 []
= (f1 5 [])++[6]
= ((f1 4 [])++[5])++[6]
...
= (...((f1 0 []) ++ [1]) ++ ...) ++ [6]
= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

And

```
f2 6 []
= (f2 5 [6])++[]
= ((f2 4 [5])++[6])++[]
...
= ((...((f2 0 [1])++[2])++ ...) ++ [6]) ++ []
= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

On the precedence of operator vs function application, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39750651/where-is-the-source-for-function-application-has-higher-precedence-than-infix/39750864).